# creating single page with 2 columns while theme is 3 column

Tags: pages, templates, sidebar, homepage, columns

I am using Diapason theme , which gives me an option for both 2 column or 3 columns...My requirement is

1:- all pages except home page (static) should have 3 columns

2:- Home Page should have two columns ( one left sidebar, and the other is main contents)

3: Header Footer and left side bar is common amongs home and other pages..

How can I do that..I know either I can use 2 columner or 3 columner, but not both at the same time..

please guide me with step by step procedure ( not the code, rather algo)

thanks to everyone trying to help me..

Comment: Columns are controlled via html elements and cascading style sheets (CSS). Control for this could be done via shortcode or via custom 'template' tools. Does this theme use shortcodes for column width?  What files are include in the directory for index.php beside footer.php and header.php?  Do you know php, html, CSS and jQuery/JavaScript?

Comment: yes, I can manage all of these..

Answer (score 1):

You should create a separate template for the home page and use that. Please refer to the [WordPress Codex Entry](http://codex.wordpress.org/Page_Templates) on templates, as it will go more in depth than I can in this answer.

You can then code the template however you would like. You can also style it however you'd like as it will add a different class to the body tag so you can target only that page. Not that a template can be reused for other pages in the future if need be.

If you don't want to reuse it consider creating a front-page.php, then changing your front page in settings > reading to the page of your choice.

Answer (score 0):

You can probably achieve that with CSS only.

The body tag for the home page has a class named "home". No other page has that class. So if you need the home page to look different you can target your tags with that class.

for example:

```
.home #main #content{

   // enter code to change the width of #content here.

}
```